# Why is the average time complexity of the find() method for unordered_set<type> container O(1)?

Tags: c++, stl, time-complexity, unordered-set

I understand the time complexity of the find() method for the STL container is constant on average, but I want to know how it is so. How does the look up through a linear data structure like an unordered set be constant time when it intuitively feels like it can never be better than linear time?

It would be really neat if someone shed some knowledge regarding the internal workings of this associative container. To put into context my extent of knowledge: I'm a second year undergrad who's been using C++ for a fair bit of time (for game development mostly, but recently also to solve leetcode problems); however, I haven't dived too deep into the internal workings of STL containers yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unordered\_Map Lookup Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25457525/unordered-map-lookup-time)

Comment: Yup. That does indeed! I need to look up what buckets are and how they work, but, it seems to be a sufficiently detailed answer for me! Thank you.